# Who are these OS-tan?

Tags: os-tan

XP-tan and 98-tan are easy to recognize, but who are the others? [This page](http://www.zerochan.net/63614) only tagged 13 with no location.

[image: OS-tan]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All the girls are [Windows OS-tan](https://ostan-collections.net/wiki/index.php?title=Windows_Family). From top to bottom, left to right, the characters/objects in that image are:

1. [NT-san](https://ostan-collections.net/wiki/index.php?title=Windows_NT)
2. [Vistake](https://ostan-collections.net/wiki/index.php?title=Windows_Vista) (Windows Vista)
3. [SE-tan](https://ostan-collections.net/wiki/index.php?title=Windows_98SE) (Windows 98SE)
4. [Dreamcast lolly](https://ostan-collections.net/wiki/index.php?title=Windows_CE)
5. [1.0-tan](http://e-shuushuu.net/search/results/?tags=59634)
6. [Inu-T](https://ostan-collections.net/wiki/index.php?title=InuT-tan) (Windows NT Workstation)
7. [DOSKitty](https://ostan-collections.net/wiki/index.php?title=Windows_3.1)
8. [WinCE](https://ostan-collections.net/wiki/index.php?title=Windows_CE)
9. [3.11-tan](https://ostan-collections.net/wiki/index.php?title=Windows_3.1)
10. [98-tan](https://ostan-collections.net/wiki/index.php?title=Windows_98)
11. [SE's mechbox](https://ostan-collections.net/wiki/index.php?title=Windows_98SE)
12. [95-tan](https://ostan-collections.net/wiki/index.php?title=Windows_95)
13. [ME-tan](https://ostan-collections.net/wiki/index.php?title=Windows_ME)
14. [2k-tan](https://ostan-collections.net/wiki/index.php?title=Windows_2000) (Windows 2000)
15. [XP-tan](https://ostan-collections.net/wiki/index.php?title=XP-tan)
16. [Homeko](https://ostan-collections.net/wiki/index.php?title=Homeko) (Windows XP Home)
17. [Moseko](https://ostan-collections.net/wiki/index.php?title=Windows_XP_Media_Center) (Windows XP Media Center Edition)